# combining detectors - requesting a reference

Tags: classification, bootstrap, ensemble-learning

I am trying to combine 5 different face detectors.

Since the detectors are imperfect, a detection can be positive on any subset of the 5 detectors, giving me (2^5 - 1) = 31 different detection scenarios (e.g. face detected on using classifiers 1,3,5 but was not detected on 2 and 4).

For each detector I have a unique feature vector output (about 100 numbers). I have ground truth for each detector, and I can know when the detected faces are the same (at about 97% reliability).

I'm looking for an algorithm which will allow me to use the combined data from all 5 detectors - even though the detectors are not well matched.

I'll reiterate the problem - each detector works in a different feature space, and detects a different scenario. I can train each detector in it's own feature space. There is some level of conjunction between the detectors. But there is no single feature matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: The area of combining classifiers is called ensemble methods. Usually, you use them in order to build the classifiers but you can use the method to combine existing learners (e.g., use the needed weight from AdaBoost).